# Creating private values from other private values in R6

Tags: r, oop, methods, private, r6

Is there any way to use a private value in order to create another private value inside `R6Class()`? I am getting errors.

```
obj <- R6Class(
  "abc",
  private = list(
    a = 2,
    b = 2*private$a
  )
)

Error in all_named(private) : object 'private' not found
```

I have also tried to create `b` with `b = 2 * a`, but it is still impossible. How should I go about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj <- R6Class(
   "abc",
  private = list(
    a = 2,
    b = function() 2*self$a
   )
)
```

Comment: I just tried it and it does not work unfortunately. Instantiating `obj` and calling the method `b` produces `NULL` instead of `4`.
Also, this is a suggestion and should not be posted as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: What else than NULL it should return? It's private. 
I've edited my answer so that it is not a suggestion any more :-)

Comment: I guess I will edit my question. I was under the impression that calling `b` from a public method would return `4`?

Comment: Alright then, I'll leave my answer nevertheless. I'd recommend reading https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html which states the essentials about OOP in R.